# Using Varnish with multiple vhosts

Tags: caching

I have varnish configured and "working" on port 80.  I have apache running a few instances of Drupal 6 on port 8080.  One for dev, review and one for production.  I used the four kitchens vcl file as a guide in setting things up.  But I'm wondering if I need to do more configuration in the VCL to separate these environments?  Perhaps separate backends?  I'm not sure when this is necessary.

In addition to this, I am not getting any (or very few) hits, mostly misses which indicates something isn't working correctly.

For reference, my vhosts looks like this...

```
NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/prod/httpdocs
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/prod_error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/prod_access.log combined

        <directory "/var/www/prod/httpdocs/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
        ServerAdmin info@mysite.com
        ServerName test.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/test/httpdocs
        ErrorLog /var/www/logs/test_error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/logs/test_access.log combined

        <directory "/var/www/test/httpdocs/">
                Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Feel free to call out anything else you see wrong with how I have configured things in apache.

Additionally, what can I do if I want my dev environment to skip caching all together?

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell what does your logs say?

Comment: The varnish logs are exhaustive.  Is there a simpler way I investigate, or a way I can make the varnish log more comprehendible.

Comment: Consider using Pressflow instead of the standard distro of Drupal. It integrates better with Varnish. Also you may need to tweak the Varnish rules to override the default cookie handling.

Answer (score 1):

You may setup different VCL configurations for your environments.

It can be easily done with wrapping them by host condition:

```
sub vcl_recv {
if (req.http.Host ~ "^example.com")
 {
 ...
  if (req.url ~ "^/something") {
   return(pass);
  }
 ...
}
}
```

Please, take a look on my blog post http://blog.tenya.me/blog/2011/12/19/varnish-simple-virtual-hosts/, it describes how to do configuration separation.